# How to call Java API from Ruby 1.8 or 1.9

Tags: ruby, api, jruby, saxon

I've this **JRuby** *working* code (stolen from [Keith's Blog](http://kfahlgren.com/blog/2007/03/02/borrowing-javas-xslt-support-for-ruby/)), which wraps the SAXON xslt processor API.

> ***Now, I wonder whether I can and how can I wrap the same API in Ruby framework?***

Please tell me if this question is non-sense or if it can be improved in some way.

This is the java doc reference for the wanted [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html).

And this is the JRuby code I'm using:

```
require 'java'
module JXslt
  include_class "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"
  include_class "javax.xml.transform.Transformer"
  include_class "javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource"
  include_class "javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult"
  include_class "java.lang.System"

  class XsltProcessor
    def transform(xslt,infile,outfile)
      transformer = @tf.newTransformer(StreamSource.new(xslt))
      transformer.transform(StreamSource.new(infile), StreamResult.new(outfile))
    end
  end # XsltProcessor
  class Saxon < XsltProcessor
    TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_IMPL = "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"
    def initialize
      System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", TRANSFORMER_FACTORY_IMPL)
      @tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: By **wrap the same API in Ruby framework** you mean not using JRuby? This isn't possible, unless you dig into C code and use the JVM C API to call java classes from C.

Comment: @Mauricio I mean: I would like to use the same module/class using Ruby interpreter (not JRuby) or wrap the API in the same way so that it can be used in Ruby. Is it possible? I need to dig into C code?

Comment: @Mauricio is it hard? Do you think a "bounty" for this question will make some answer appear?

Comment: It isn't simple, as you would have to call C code from Ruby and then from C code call Java code to execute whatever you would like to execute. Here's an article about how to call Java from C code -> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CJniJava.aspx - if I were you, I would surely stay with JRuby instead of doing this.

Comment: @Mauricio thanks, I'm thinking about Ruby, because there is no any similar class in Ruby itself. I'll have a look at that article.

Comment: No there isn't, you will have to write a C library that calls the Java classes and then, in Ruby, write a wrapper that will call this C library you have built. You can use FFI for that - https://github.com/ffi/ffi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented above, you can not do this directly from the Ruby runtime, calling Java from Ruby requires you to be either on JRuby or call Java indirectly using the C/C++ JVM API that allows you to call Java code from C.

The first option is possibly using [Ruby Java Bridge](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/) that does most of the heavy lifting for you (it functions as a Ruby-to-C-to-Java wrapper).

If RJB doesn't work for you, you can also build your wrapper directly by using the JVM API in C ( [example here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CJniJava.aspx) ) and then you could call it from Ruby using [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi).

But unless you really need to use the C-Ruby (MRI) I would greatly recommend you to avoid any of the approaches above and just use JRuby, as delving into native code will lead to possible segfaults, memory management issues and all options above force you to run in a single thread, while you could build a multi-threaded solution by using JRuby.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Can't provide a real feedback as did not try it and have no enough experience to assert. However it sounds correct (and not easy :( and nobody provided any alternative. Anyway, I will follow your last suggestion, staying with jruby. Thanks.