# Integrate Java Tools with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, rjb

I am looking into finding a solution for invoking JAVA APIs to perform set of operations before request is received by a web application written in Ruby on Rails.
I looked at various approaches and found that rack middleware can be helpful. A module written in ruby can be specified on top of middleware stack.

But how to call JAVA APIs from ruby. Ruby on Bridge is one of solution for it, is it stable?
or is there any other approach for achieving what I wanted to?
Any thoughts on using JRuby.

Comment: This previous post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284161/how-to-call-java-api-from-ruby-1-8-or-1-9

Comment: What's your Java API like?  Is it a native Java API, or is it exposed as a HTTP service?