# How do I use a Java library (like JDBC) in C Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, jdbc, rubygems

My code depends on some gems that are only available in C Ruby so I cannot use JRuby.
Is there any way to use java libraries such as JDBC drivers in C Ruby?

Comment: In a word, no; JDBC is JVM-only. CRuby has its own DB driver packages.

Comment: Our database server only support JDBC connection. Matlab can interop with JVM and .NET,etc. It is a surprise that CRuby which claimed itself as a glue language cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cribbing an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284161/how-to-call-java-api-from-ruby-1-8-or-1-9):

You could [build a wrapper using the C JVM API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI) and then [call it from Ruby using FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Basic-Usage), or you could use a project called [Ruby Java Bridge (RJB)](https://github.com/arton/rjb).